# Lua Script to insert 100000 random keys on redis

Tags: lua, redis

I need to test this on some redis instances.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

```
for i = 1, 100000, 1 do
    redis.call("SET", "ZzZ_MYKEY_ZzZ_"..i.."key", i)
end

return "Ok!"
```

Save this as `redis_load.lua`and execute with `redis-cli --eval redis_load.lua`

Answer (score 3):

Redis' Lua scripts (try to) prevent you from doing random writes, the reason being that it would break replication. While arguably there ways to work around that restriction, you really shouldn't :) Instead of try to Lua your way, consider using redis-benchmark (or memtier-benchmark) to populate your database with random values.

That said, if this is a once off, you could generate the keys with Lua. Further more, with v3.2's new effect-based replication you can even do really random stuff.

Comment: It would break replication _in a cluster setup specifically_. In sentinel mode, random writes are just fine. In fact, in even cluster mode, random writes are fine. It's _random reads_ that are the problem in cluster mode (but not sentinel mode). Moreso, it's been widely discussed that cluster mode is not recommended for most redis setups and that sentinel mode (or even better, KeyDB's sentinel mode) is better.

Comment: I concur that this is *totally* not cluster-safe.